# Where is UNIQUE 125kHz protocol specified?

Tags: rfid

I am working on a RFID reader project and I can't find 125kHz UNIQUE tag specification (like listed in [this TWN4 reader spec](http://www.rfidsystems.com.br/en/pdf/500.614_500.615_500.640_500.641_Multitag_Folheto_en.pdf)). I could easily find the datasheets for EM4100, EM4200, EM4102 tags.

[One tag I've found](http://www.cyntag.com/IC_datasheets/UNIQUE%20-%20V2%20-%206815.pdf) uses the term "UNIQUE" but has EM4102 chip inside.

Questions:

1. Is the UNIQUE tag a specific RFID standard or is it only a marketing term?
2. If it is a standard - where can I find the specification of the UNIQUE tag protocol/data format?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find this [link](https://shopdelta.eu/unique-125khz-rfid-standard_l2_aid901.html) which talks about some of the specifications of UNIQUE 125KHz. hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

"Unique" applies to customer 8 bit ID on chip for 64 bit Read Only memory (EM 4102). These are first two "nibbles" P0,P1 of memory.